# Set hasOne() dropdown field as readonly in forms

Tags: php, frameworks, atk4

There are a number of post about setting fields in forms to read only, but none that seem to cover hasOne() fields. I wish to edit a list of students (enrolments) that belong to a given class. The class is for a particular subject, e.g. maths, and stores the period of time and maximum number of students. When editing the enrolments I want the class details to be read only, whilst the students that belong to the class editable via CRUD. I can set the native fields of a model by calling display() for each field (e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/agile-toolkit-devel/v2xVYsRqFpY ), but I cannot find a method for setting hasOne.

Below is the code I have so far.

Subject model

```
class Model_Subject extends Model_Table {
public $table='subject';

function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->addField('name');
        $this->addField('subject_code');
        $this->addField('semester');
        $this->addField('description');

}
}
```

Class model

```
class Model_Class extends Model_Table {
    public $table='class';

    function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->hasOne('Subject');
        $this->addField('date_start')->type('date')->caption('Start');
        $this->addField('date_end')->type('date')->caption('End');
        $this->addField('max_students')->type('int');

        $this->hasMany('ClassHasStudent','class_idclass', 'idclass');
    }
}
```

Student model

```
class Model_Student extends Model_Table {
    public $table='student';

    function init(){
        parent::init();

        $this->hasMany('ClassJoinClassHasStudent');
        $this->addField('student_ID')->caption('Student ID');
        $this->addField('name')->caption('Name');

        $this->addExpression('number_classes')->set(
                $this->add('Model_ClassHasStudent')->addCondition('student_id',$this->_dsql()->getField('id'))->count()
        )->caption('Number of classes');
    }

}
```

Linking table.

```
class Model_ClassHasStudent extends Model_Table {
public $table='class_has_student';

function init(){
    parent::init();

    $this->hasOne('Class', 'class_id', 'id');
    $this->hasOne('Student');

    $this->addField('date_enrolled')->type('date');
    $this->addField('grade');

}
}
```

And the form is:

```
$form=$this->add('MVCForm');
$classes=$this->add('Model_Class');

// $classes-> set hasOne Subject name field to read only.

$classes->getField('date_start')->display(array('form'=>'readonly'));
$classes->getField('date_end')->display(array('form'=>'readonly'));
$classes->getField('max_students')->display(array('form'=>'readonly'));

// Method from Romans.
$form->model->load($id);
$this->add('CRUD')->setModel($form->model->ref('ClassHasStudent'));

$form->addSubmit('Save');

$form->onSubmit( function($form){

    $form->update();
    return $form->js()->univ()->location($form->api->getDestinationURL(
            'managestudents',
            array('id'=>false)));

});
```

Also, if I set  $this->hasOne('Subject')->readonly(true); in the Model_Class then the form displays the subject id as text rather than the 'name' of the subject.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which version of ATK4 are you using? Why you use MVCForm which I guess is controller and not add(Form)?
You should better take part in discussion about readonly (and editable, disabled, hidden, system etc.) fields in this Google groups topic. Right now display(form=>readonly) and readonly(true) in model are two different cases. I made some changes in model readonly(true), but we need to discuss how to do that correctly. I see Romans have come up with something too recently. Sorry, have no time tonight to check that out.

Comment: I just realised that display(array('form'=>'readonly')) has a problem, when saving the form those fields set with display(array('form'=>'readonly')) are replaced with NULL in the table. This is noted in the discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/agile-toolkit-devel/v2xVYsRqFpY.

Comment: Sorry DarkSide, just read your comment. I got the latest github version. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem now with display(form=>readonly). My changes are not posted in github version because we still have a discussion about how everything should work with these field types/attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the model:

```
$this->hasOne('Subject'); // will create 'subject' and 'subject_id' fields
$this->getElement('subject')
    ->editable(true)
    ->display(array('form'=>'readonly'));
```

hasOne creates two fields. The dereferenced field (without _id) is a calculated field which is excluded from the form by default. By setting 'editable' you can return it into the form (event through it's calculated) and set the display property. Alternatively you can do this:

```
$forms->getElement('subject_id')->setAttr('disabled',true);
```

This will still use the drop-down but it will be disabled. I'm not 100% positive but any jQueriUI enhancements (such as auto-complete) must respect disabled property.